# Writing multiple wav files from NAudio asioOut

Tags: c#, wav, naudio, asio

I'm trying to record 3-4 streams of audio and write them to separate wav files.  I'm using NAudio's asioOut to capture the audio.  At first I was just writing a 3 or 4 channel wav file.  So I searched questions here and thought I founded an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075062/saving-each-wav-channel-as-a-mono-channel-wav-file-using-naudio), but I still can't figure it out.  Now I can write the separate wav files but they have multiple channels in each file.

channel_1.wav --------> has channel 1 and 2

channel_2.wav --------> has channel 1 and 3

channel_3.wav --------> has channel 2 and 3

I think there is a problem when I try to parse the *GetAsInterleavedSamples()*.

This is my asioOut_AudioAvailable()

```
    void asioOut_AudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
    {     

        float[] samples = new float[2 * 44100 * GetUserSpecifiedChannelCount()];

        samples = e.GetAsInterleavedSamples();

        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < samples.Length)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < this.writers.Length; n++)
            {
                this.writers[n].WriteSamples(samples, offset, 2);
                offset += 2;
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm new at this so I'm just learning as a go, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you  correctly, you only want to write one sample to each writer, so the third parameter for `WriteSamples` should be 1, and offset should be incremented by 1. You've probably copied the +=2 from an example that is dealing with 16 bit audio in a byte array.

Comment: Is this solution still relevant in 2023? I tried it, but I get zero bytes being recorded in the two wavefileWriters I tried. Please can this solution be updated. Thanks