# Getting multiple audio samples from naudio GetAsInterleavedSamples using asioOut

Tags: c#, naudio, asio

After checking out this link:
[Writing multiple wav files from NAudio asioOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077743/writing-multiple-wav-files-from-naudio-asioout), I wanted to be able to get separate wave samples into different files, but it's not working. I'm only getting zero-byte files. I don't know if an update has been made to the naudio library since 2012, when the solution was posted.
Please what adjustment do I make to my code below to get the various wave samples into different files. Currently I'm getting multiple zero-byte files without any errors

My code below:

```
    private WaveFileWriter[] writer = null;
    private AsioOut asioOut;
    private string[] fileName = null;
    private int recordChannelCount;

    private void Start()
    {
        // allow change device
        if (asioOut != null &&
            (asioOut.DriverName != comboBoxAsioDevice.Text ||
            asioOut.ChannelOffset != GetUserSpecifiedChannelOffset()))
        {
            asioOut.AudioAvailable -= OnAsioOutAudioAvailable;
            asioOut.Dispose();
            asioOut = null;
        }

        recordChannelCount = GetUserSpecifiedChannelCount();

        // create device if necessary
        if (asioOut == null)
        {
            asioOut = new AsioOut(comboBoxAsioDevice.Text);
            asioOut.InputChannelOffset = GetUserSpecifiedChannelOffset();
            asioOut.InitRecordAndPlayback(null, recordChannelCount, 44100);
            asioOut.AudioAvailable += OnAsioOutAudioAvailable;
        }

        filename = new string[recordChannelCount];
        writer = new WaveFileWriter[recordChannelCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < recordChannelCount; i++)
        {
            filename[i] = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"Record{i+1}"  + ".wav");
            writer[i] = new WaveFileWriter(fileName[i], new WaveFormat(44100, recordChannelCount));
        }
        
        asioOut.Play();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        SetButtonStates();
    }

    void OnAsioOutAudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
    {
      #pragma warning disable 618
        float[] samples = new float[2 * 44100 * GetUserSpecifiedChannelCount()];
        samples = e.GetAsInterleavedSamples();
      #pragma warning restore 618
        
        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < writer. Length; i++)
        {
            //writer[i].WriteSamples(samples, 0, samples.Length); //works but writes same thing
            writer[i].WriteSamples(samples, offset, 1); //Not working
            offset += 1;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So apparently you can de-interleave the getasinterleavedsamples. The process is known as jagged arrays, i.e. storing arrays inside arrays. So the function below will help to get the individual samples into its own float arrays:

```
    public static void DeInterleave(float[] interleavedData, int channels, out float[][] deinterleavedData)
    {
        int samplesPerChannel = interleavedData.Length / channels;
        deinterleavedData = new float[channels][];

        for (int channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++)
        {
            deinterleavedData[channel] = new float[samplesPerChannel];

            for (int sample = 0; sample < samplesPerChannel; sample++)
            {
                int interleavedIndex = sample * channels + channel;
                deinterleavedData[channel][sample] = interleavedData[interleavedIndex];
            }
        }
    }
```

And you can get each individual samples float using the code below:

```
float[][] deinterleavedData;
DeInterleave(samples, channels, out deinterleavedData);
```

Then loop through deinterleavedData to get the sample.
I hope it helps somebody.