# Distorted audio when splitting 2 channel wav file into mono channel wav files

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am using NAudio to split a 2 channel wav file which is also generated by recording using Wasapi included in NAudio. I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075062/saving-each-wav-channel-as-a-mono-channel-wav-file-using-naudio/12149659#12149659) as an example to split the 2 channel wav file. The following is my code:

```
WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(outputFileName + "ORIGINAL.WAV");
var buffer = new byte[2 * reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate * reader.WaveFormat.Channels];
var format = new WaveFormat(reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 32, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < writers.Length; i++)
{
    writers[i] = new WaveFileWriter(String.Format(outputFileName + "{0}.wav", i), format);
    logevent.writeToLog(Convert.ToString(newWaveIn.WaveFormat.Channels));
}

int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < bytesRead)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < writers.Length; i++)
        {
            writers[i].Write(buffer, offset, 2);
            offset += 2;
         }
    }
}
```

The bit rate for the recorded audio is 2822kbps. The two output wav files are 1058kbps each and the sound becomes jitter or a very loud white noise when played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's 32 bit audio you're dealing with, then you need to write four bytes at a time, not two in your loop

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also had to change the waveformat to IeeeWaveformat since the encoding was not pcm.